# Multiples modules reading same fifo

Tags: module, fifo, systemc

Is it possible to instantiate multiple modules to read from the same fifo assuming they are not reading at the same time, but take turns??

For example:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sc_fifo<int> PacketTx(24);
    sc_fifo<int> PacketRx(20);

    Transmit t1("Transmit");
    t1.PacketRx(PacketRx);
    t1.PacketTx(PacketTx);

    Receive r1("Receive1");
    r1.PacketTx(PacketRx);
    r1.PacketRx(PacketTx);

    Receive r2("Receive2");
    r2.PacketTx(PacketRx);
    r2.PacketRx(PacketTx);

    sc_start();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but you need to add synchronization signals to the module's.

For sample implementation closer to your requirement is available under SystemC source code from [Accellera SystemC](http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/systemc) download page.

Download the "**Core SystemC Language and Examples**" zip file:

- Unzip the file.
- Navigate into the directory and look for "**examples**" directory.

Following example are much closer to your requirement:

- examples/sysc/pkt_switch/
  **Note:** This example does not use sc_fifo's but utilizes the sc_in/out port's.
- examples/sysc/simple_bus/
  **Note:**  This example showcase the use-case to model CPU bus model. This example also currently does not utilize the sc_fifo.

But you can get much better ideas for your implementation details.